# Pressure sense in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, pressure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tap pressure strength detection using accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179426/tap-pressure-strength-detection-using-accelerometer)

I've found the video introducing iPad2.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nP_hhrkdrE

at 3:40, when you hit on the drum harder, the louder the sound produced.

I've kept search a lot on Apple developer's API and cannot find such techniques, so how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5179426/388318

Comment: using accelerometer only sense **the first time pressure only**, as Joe Blow answered below, and that's not what I need. And the topic is related to accelerometer only. 

is there other methods to sense the pressure without using accelerometer?